# Jenkins Pipeline Plugin execute two pipelines in parallel and make downstream pipeline wait

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

We are using Jenkins and the [Pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) for CI/CD.  We have two pipelines that we need to run parallel, and there is a downstream pipeline which should trigger ONLY if the two upstream pipelines both finish and are successful.

```
P1--
    | -- P3
P2--
```

Basically P3 should run only when P1 and P2 are finished and successful and not depend on just one of them.

Is there a way to achieve this?  We are using 2.5 version of the plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since stages only run if previous stages run successfully, and since you can execute other pipelines via `build`, and since there is a magical instruction called `parallel`, I think this might do it:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  stages {
    stage("build_p1_and_p2_in_parallel") {
      steps {
        parallel p1: {
          build 'p1'
        }, p2: {
          build 'p2'
        }
      }
    }
    stage("build_p3_if_p1_and_p2_succeeded") {
      steps {
        build 'p3'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Use the "Snippet Generator" embedded in your jenkins instance to figure out what the argument to `build` should be. If it's another pipeline at the same level as the top level Jenkinsfile, you could just reference it by job name. Caveat: I've used `parallel`, but never `build` within `parallel`, but it seems like it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and wrap the pipelines jobs with [MultiJob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) that can implement the logic that you require as 2 jobs inside a phase.

Comment: Multijob plugin does not run pipelines as the feature is not yet supported.

Comment: yes, we know. Soon we'll publish a new plugin that does the same with pipelines